# Shear stress calculation due to surfactant molecules

Tags: fluid-statics

I have an interface of two immiscible liquids. Is there a way to calculate the shear stress at this interface as a function of surfactant concentration?

Comment: There is normally no shear stress in liquids unless the liquids are flowing, in which case it's proportional to the shear rate. Did you mean the *surface tension* rather than the *shear stress*?

Comment: I mean shear stress. My understanding is that presence of surfactant molecules will cause additional stress on the interface which will tend to deform it. I just want to know if this can be related to concentration of surfactants.

Comment: You'll need to provide a link to whatever article is claiming surfactants "*will cause additional stress on the interface which will tend to deform it*". This is not something I have encountered. All surfactants will do is lower the surface tension of the interface between the liquids.

Comment: I am referring to this article: https://journals.aps.org/prfluids/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevFluids.3.024003 especially first paragraph of the Introduction.

Comment: The paper is titled "Enhanced interfacial deformation in a Marangoni flow:
A measure of the dynamical surface tension".

Comment: That paper describes a flow that occurs when there is a surface tension gradient due to the concentration of the surfactant being different at different parts of the surface. This is a dynamical effect since at equilibrium the concentration of the surfactant will be the same everywhere and the gradient will be zero. The flow is not specifically a property of the surfactant but of how the surfactant is being delivered to the surface.

Comment: Though to be fair it is an interesting paper. Thanks for the link :-)